# Is there a way to use own component class that extends React.Component without a need to import react in every file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have created my own typescript abstract class, that extends React.Component.
I want to use this class as a base for every component in my application.
However it doesn't work if I don't add an import statement of React - JSX syntax produces an error.

I would like to completely abstract React.Component and use my own base class, so maybe in the future I would want to switch from react to something else. The required import statement makes it a little cumbersome.

Is there maybe a way to import something globally in typescript, or any other solution for that?

I don't use webpack or babel as those are separate, reusable packages in my lerna monorepo.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you write something like `<div>`, the JSX Factory transforms the JSX into a valid JavaScript/TypeScript function call, in this case `React.createElement('div', ..`.

This is well explained in the [JSX Introduction](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects) on React.js website.

So, as you can see `React` *should* be defined since it is called in your code. If you want to switch to something else, you will need to change the [jsx factory function with the so-called `pragma`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#factory-functions), which is, the replacement for `React` in the JSX compilation, and replace your imports.